# Docker's container name can not be resolved

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I just tried to create two containers for Elastic Search and Kibana.

```
docker network create esnetwork
docker run --name myes --net esnetwork -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -p 127.0.0.1:9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:7.9.3
```

and Elastic Search works when I use `http://localhost:9200` or `http://internal-ip:9200`
But when I use `http://myes:9200`, it just can't resolve the container name.

Thus when I run

```
docker run --name mykib --net esnetwork -p 5601:5601 -e “ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://myes:9200” docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.9.3
```

It couldn't be created because it cannot resolve `myes:9200`
I also tried to replace "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://myes:9200" with `localhost:9200` or internal IP instead. but nothing works.
So I think my question should be how to make the container's DNS works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this problem doesn't arise from DNS. Both Elastic search and Kibana containers should use the fix name "elasticsearch" . so the docker command will be:

```
$docker network create esnetwork

$sudo vi /etc/sysctl.d/max_map_count.conf
vm.max_map_count=262144

$docker run --name elasticsearch --net esnetwork -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -p 127.0.0.1:9300:9300 -e 

$docker run --name kib01-test --net esnetwork -p 5601:5601 -e “ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200” docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.9.3
```

Then if the terminals that run installations could be ended automatically, just close them. And restart containers from the docker desktop manager. Then everything will go smoothly.

My environment is Fedora 36, docker 20.10.18

Answer (score 0):

How are you resolving 'myes'?
Is it mapped in hostname file and resolving to 127.0.0.1?
Also, use 127.0.0.1 wherever possible as localhost could be pointing to something else and not getting resolved.

Comment: Sorry. I know there will be a solution like manually changing hostname file. I think my questions. I still remember the docker could solve the problem by itself, how can I recover it?

Comment: I didn't get your query actually. Could you elaborate?